# How to add a custom content type in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, cms

I am very new to Magento. My requirement is to add a **Pro Staff** section. Pro staff content would have some attribute fields and references to products. In front-end there will be a category wise display of all contents, which leads to its own pages.

I am planning to done this using a custom type, like custom content type in Drupal or custom post type in WordPress. How can I create a custom content type?

OR

Is there any other methods, modules or connectors, to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Very limited in scope is the blog functionality given for FREE :

Magento 1.x :
https://marketplace.magento.com/aheadworks-aw-blog.html 
Magento 2.x :
https://marketplace.magento.com/magefan-module-blog.html

so you can create blog posts and also provides a page that lists all blog posts with pager.
Unfortunately some basic functionalities of other CMS's are available only as paid in Magento.

If you want to go with a PAID solution this extension  :

Magento 1.x:
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-content-manager-improve-your-cms-1.html 
Magento 2.x :
https://marketplace.magento.com/blackbird-contentmanager.html

This extension promises to do exactly what you need: create custom content types.

Perhaps you can create your own functionality after studying the free solution given above and create your own extension with you own custom type.

Comment: HOW!!! did I not know that https://www.advancedcontentmanager.com/en/advanced-content-manager-m1.html existed. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Enother methods :
1.Read more about local.xml.
2.read more about static blocks ( they are very easy to use and learn)
3. Read more about model, collections in magento (create your table in db , save some atributes, get them on the frontend , and show them).

If you have any questions , i support you ( give some supports)